# making macOS app scriptable at a 'Linux' way

Tags: macos, applescript

I've implemented a macOS app.
Is it possible to make it scriptable?
for example - let's say the app's name is "myApp", and within the app you can add/delete new users, and press a button, I want to be able to control the app from the terminal with something like this:

//initiate commands:

myApp --addUser 'Bob'

//when the app is already running commands:

myApp --pressButton 'BigRedButton'

Or in other words, something like:
myApp  ...

P.S - I know about AppleScript, but never tried it before, and it seems a little too complicated for the things I want to do, so I'm wondering if there's another way, or maybe AppleScript is the only way..

Comment: AppleScript is the only reasonable way. Of course you can write your own scripting interface (maybe web based) but it's still more complicated than the Cocoa Scripting Framework

Comment: K, if tit's the only reasonable way you can write this comment as an answer and I'll accept it as the correct one

Answer (score 1):

raywenderlich.com has two excellent tutorials on the kind of scripting you're asking about.

I would agree that there's a lot you can do with Applescript, and it's pretty straightforward to do if you're already comfortable working in the language.  Here's a tutorial on how to implement Applescriptability into your app:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/1033-making-a-mac-app-scriptable-tutorial

But to your point, yes, this is only step 1 if you're dealing with Applescript.  Step 2 is writing an actual Applescript to pass the commands you're looking to execute to your application.

And no, that still doesn't get you what you're asking for.  If what you **really** need to do is pass commands from the command line, I'd start here:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/511-command-line-programs-on-macos-tutorial

That tutorial deals more with how to create an actual command-line app (that is, one with no actual GUI), but the principles are going to be the same & you should be able to use these same methods to implement code into your app that will allow it to listen for commands issued from the command line.